# LinkPager widget in Yii 2 generating double ? because of route rule

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have done up a pagination system and am using the [LinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html) widget, however this is generating links with `??` at the start instead of `?` as it should.

This appears to be because of my UrlManager rule:

```
'foo/<name:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+>.<some_id:\d+>/?' => 'foo/index',
```

I need to include that `?` on the end or it can't resolve the page with an ending slash.

Here is how I am calling `LinkPager`:

```
LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination, 'options' => ['class' => 'clearfix']]);
```

Where `$pagination` is obviously the [Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) instance.

Is there any way I can stop it including the double question marks?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this part of the url `<some_id:\d+>/?` ? I'm pretty sure the reason of duplicate question mark is that question mark in the end of the rule.

Comment: Just as I said in my question. I want the route to work with or without the ending slash, but unless I include the `?` on the end of the rule it only works without the ending slash.

Comment: You put this outside of pattern. As for ending slash, it's not possible configure it here, I already answered similar question today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018061/yii2-url-mapping-suffix/28018228#28018228

Comment: Dang. That's annoying behavior then :( So if I wanted to add a suffix of `/` how would I do it? I noticed the other guy had written his rules a bit different to mine.

Comment: Yes, it's extended format of specifying the rules. The essence is you can't make this optional here. So you want make this required and page accessible with trailing slash?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I prefer to have the trailing slash. But think I know how to specify it now..... just use they key names like he has.

Comment: Issued this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the url rule: `/?`. You can't specify trailing slash like that, regex is wrong and outside of the pattern. Also you can't make it optional.

If you want to have the trailing slash, change the rule declaration to extended version and specify slash as `suffix` like that:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'foo/<name:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+>.<some_id:\d+>',
    'route' => 'foo/index',
    'suffix' => '/',
],
```

Read more about alternative format of specifying url rules in [corresponding section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules) of official documentation.

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018061/yii2-url-mapping-suffix/).